# CollapsingToolbarLayout title disappearing when overlapped by side drawer

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-support-design

I updated revision of the Support Design Library to 23.0.1 and got such behaviour - title disappears, when overlapped by side drawer (drawer is simple LinearLayout with custom childrens). There was no problem, when I used rev. 22.2.1. Do you have any thoughts about what mechanism hides a title?

See video
https://youtu.be/pYVQR-q6ylo

Comment: Did you solve your issue in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183333). I hope Chris Banes will fix it soon.

Comment: It should be fixed in v23.1.0 release.